# Textfields in android

Tags: java, android, textfield

I hope someone can help! I'm fairly new to android and am having a problem with textfields. I have 3 textfields that require the user to enter info, when the register button is clicked a message will let the user know they are registered and redirect them to login activity.
My problem is that I want to check if the user has completed all 3 textfields and if not display an error message and allow them to try again. I can display the error message but even when all textfields are not complete if the reg button is clicked it still tells  user they are registered and redirects user to the login activity, I have posted my code if someone could tell me were I am going wrong, thanks in advance!

```
@Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   String data1 = inputName.getText().toString();
        if(data1.trim().equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Please enter your name",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
   String data2 = inputEmail.getText().toString();
        if(data2.trim().equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "please enter email address",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
   String data3 = inputPassword.getText().toString();
        if(data3.trim().equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Please enter a password",
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

   if(data1 != null && data2 != null && data3!= null){
   mySQLiteAdapter.insert(data1, data2, data3);
   updateList();
   Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "You are now registered",
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class));
   inputName.setText("");
   inputEmail.setText("");
   inputPassword.setText("");
  }
        else Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Error please try again!",
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

   };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
if(data1 != null && data2 != null && data3!= null)
```

Those are not `null`, just empty strings (`""`). This is always true.

Comment: off topic: you've got a really nice name -- wonder how you did it.

Comment: There's two or three unicode characters there. The rest are all regular letters, look closer ;)

Comment: Yeah, I see now -- thought you somehow injected some "mirror/upside down" special character :-) Congratulations to that unique name

Answer (score 0):

You can olso use `TextUtils.isEmpty(string)`

```
   if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(data1) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(data2) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(data2)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "All three Strings are not empty or null!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your helpful answers, i think i have solved my problem! hope my solution helps someone else!

```
@Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   String data1 = inputName.getText().toString();
   String data2 = inputEmail.getText().toString();
   String data3 = inputPassword.getText().toString();

   boolean invalid = false;

    if(data1.equals("")){
        invalid = true;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username Missing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else if(data2.equals("")){
        invalid = true;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email ID Missing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else if(data3.equals("")){
        invalid = true;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password Missing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if(invalid == false){
        mySQLiteAdapter.insert(data1, data2, data3);
           updateList();
           Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "You are now registered",
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent i_register = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(i_register);

        inputName.setText("");
        inputEmail.setText("");
        inputPassword.setText("");
        finish();
    }   

   /*mySQLiteAdapter.insert(data1, data2, data3);
   updateList();
   Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "You are now registered",
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class));*/


  }

   };
```